# SSAS Cube design - MDX very slow

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, cross-join, microstrategy

I'm busy tearing my hair out with this one. I have a cube with 1 fact and around 9 dimensions. The fact table only has around 120k rows in it so it is not a big DB by any means.

The issue is that with the reporting software I'm using (Microstrategy), the MDX it generates grabs all the data and uses that as a data source (instead of generating the MDX as you manipulate the reports).
Either way, when adding a couple of fields the query quickly becomes unusable, and actually runs out of memory. I suspect it has something to do with my cube design.

For one, it does a cross-join on all the attributes, even if they're on the same dimension, as if it doesn't realize that there is a relationship between them.

I have played around with attribute relationships in BIDS (making the relationships rigid where possible) but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

The MDX generated is shown below. I don't have the option of customizing the MDX but I'm sure I'm not telling it what the relationships are correctly.

I have tried posting on the Microstrategy support site without too much joy.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
WITH SET AS '{[Dim Date].[Date].[Date].AllMembers}'
...
(all my dimensions appear here)
...
select {[Measures].[Total Purchases], [Measures].[New Cards Issued], [Measures].[New     Applications Received], [Measures].[New Applications Declined], [Measures].[New     Applications Approved], [Measures].[New Accounts Activated]} on columns,
non empty CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(C  ROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN([dim0_select_members], [dim1_select_members]), [dim2_select_members]), [dim3_select_members]), [dim4_select_members]), [dim5_select_members]), [dim6_select_members]), [dim7_select_members]), [dim8_select_members]), [dim9_select_members]), [dim10_select_members]), [dim11_select_members]), [dim12_select_members]), [dim13_select_members]), [dim14_select_members]), [dim15_select_members]), [dim16_select_members]), [dim17_select_members]) on rows
from [Cards_Transactions]
```

Comment: Does that mean the query that Microstrategy is issuing contains all measures and all attributes in the cube, independent of the query that the user issues? BTW: Analysis Services uses `autoexists` within one dimension. That means that within one dimension, `CrossProduct` does only ever deliver rows where the combination exists. That is independent of the relationships you define.

Comment: Do the attributes have parent-child relationships? I used some SSAS cube in MicroStrategy in the past without any big trouble.

Answer (score 2):

it will be good if you can elaborate on your needs.

is it for end users or developers?
Do you want to allow users to perform self-service on the mdx cube?
Does the data they are query needs to be live (updated to now) or it can be updated till the previous hour\day...?

there are 2 ways to connect to MDX sources in MSTR.

one way is - Direct Connection trough the Import Data interface.

with this way - mstr generates mdx queries according to your selections on-the-fly. that is why it is important to use some filters before dragging some attributes to the screen in Visual insight.

the second option is to [connect MSTR to the MDX cube at the schema level](http://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/10.1/manuals/en/MDXCubeReporting.pdf).
it reads the cube definition and creates attributes and metrics as they exists in your cube. it also allows you to map MDX attribute to a project Attribute in order to enforce security filters.
this way you can build regular reports (you can also use prompts and filters...) and you can build i-cubes from the mdx cube.

you might find the second option more suitable for your needs.

since your MDX cube is very small i would suggest you to create an i-cube + incremental refresh report to update it (for example - update every 5 minutes with today's data).